# Why isn't the on-camera flash of SLR or compact cameras tiltable?

Tags: flash, popup-flash

All external flash tilt, and isn't it simple and apparent to add this to the design?

I mean, take a look at this [horror](http://www.sublime-light.com/index.php/2007/08/13/diy-use-off-camera-lighting-if-you-dont-own-a-flash/)...

[image]

Comment: To avoid that monster - there's this http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/pop-up-flash-bounce/

Comment: Panasonic gx1 as a tiltable flash

Answer (score 8):

The [Panasonic L1](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/cameras/panasonic-l1.shtml) *did* have such a flash, but was (I think for other reasons) largely a flop. It's hard to speculate exactly why this hasn't caught on, but I assume that it's largely because:

1. The built-in flash, for size and because it uses the main battery, can't be very powerful, and bouncing takes more power, so the utility is lessened.
2. Even a clever design would take a bit more space, be more expensive, and be more fragile. All of these factors may be judged — by the camera makers or by the camera market — to be more important.
3. Most people don't care, and those that do are prime targets for the lucrative accessory flash market.

PS: some entry-level add-on flashes don't tilt either.

Comment: 2's a big one -- can you imagine the warranty repairs?

Answer (score 3):

I think the market is vanishingly small for the trouble (warranties, price, etc) it would cause.
You're talking about a group of people who:

1. Want flash.
2. Don't want so much flash that they're investing in real flash gear.
3. Don't want a simple accessory like [this](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/pop-up-flash-bounce/) but would be willing to pay more probably to have it as a 'feature' on camera.
4. Won't be using it in many situations where the the popup flash is just grossly under-powered.

Overall, its good economics for them.  They're promoting their lucrative flash market and leaving the small bits to an accessory market.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't that simple. A tiltable flash would be a lot more complex and costly, it would make the camera larger, and it would have to be much more powerful so it would drain the camera battery in no time.

It would make the camera so much more expensive that you would pay extra as much as for the external flash, but you would still not get something that is nearly as flexible and usable.

Top end SRLs doesn't even have the built in flash, because you'll want to use an external flash anyway.

Comment: Come on the flash is itself on a joint already as it pops up, what's the difficulty of adding another joint in the middle to turn the flash up?

Comment: @nuno_cruz. Don't ask us, write to Nikon and Canon